# filter not showing results

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-router-dom

I am trying to filter through an array of object and render the title and overview of that into the page. I use the ID to find what I am looking for, however, when I use .filter it doesn't seem to find the id.

[image: the code]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `id` from `useParams` is a string but on your objects it's a number. Either use the `==` equality operator or make a type conversion (e.g., `String(data.id) === id`)

Comment: Did you make sure the `id` field from `useParam` does exist and is not `undefined`? I don't see any problems in your code so far. Also, consider using `id` instead of `index` as the `key` of the component(s), in case you have to re-arrange the array in the future (e.g. dynamically add/remove/filter/sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id returned from the useParams will be a string . So you can do a casting of your ID to number and then do the comparison .

data.id === Number(id)

Comment: Thank I didn't even notice that useParams return a string. It works now thank you.

Comment: The reason it is a string is when you do `someRoute/${id}` . Your Id gets typecasted to String .